# How can I check the "check property again" without reloading again?

Tags: angular, typescript

My problem is the following:
I have two child components, 1. buttons, 2. detail

```
//button.component.ts
deleteAll(){
  this.srv.array = [];
}
```

The array is from the service which I use to check whether a checkbox should be checked or not. 
I compare the elements of the array with the fields I display. If they have the same name the checkbox is checked:

```
// details.component.ts
  checkedItems(item){
    for(let k=0;k<this.array.length;k++){ //the array from the service is assigned to this array on 
       if(condition)                      ngOnInit
       return true;
   } 
 }
```

Property-binding in details.component.ts:

```
...
       <label><input  type="checkbox" 
        [checked]="checkedItems(field)" // important
        (click)="check(field, $event)"> 
        {{name}} 
      </label>
...
```

Instead of switching the pages to see that fields are unchecked now, I want the field to update immediatley. The problem is I do not know how to call `detectChanges` or how to use `ngOnchanges` in my case between the two child components.
How could I reload the child component or check the fields again after calling `deleteAll`

Comment: You can use ChangeDetectorRef and its markForCheck method

Comment: Try creating a stackblitz of this example and/or possibly including your entire template, service, and component code so we can get a clearer picture of what your trying to do. https://stackblitz.com